# Talend open studio run only created or modified records among 15k

Tags: talend

I have a job in talend open studio which is working fine, it conects a tMSSqlinput to a tMap then tMysqlOutput, very straight forward. My problem is that i need this job running on daily basis, but only run when a new record is created or modified...any help is highly aprecciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are searching for a [Change Data Capture Tool for Talend](https://fr.talend.com/resource/change-data-capture.html).
Unfortunately it is only available on the licenced product.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your need, you do have several ways. I want to show the most popular ones.

**CDC from Talend**

As Corentin said correctly, you could choose to use CDC (Change Data Capture) from Talend if you use the subscription version.

**CDC of MSSQL**

Alternatively you can check if you can activate or use CDC in your MSSQL server. This depends on your license. If it is possible, you can use the function to identify new elements and proceed them.

**Triggers**

Also you can create triggers on your database (if you have access to it). For example, creating a trigger for the cases INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE would help you getting the deltas. Then you could store those records separately or their IDs.

**Software driven / API**

If your database is connected to a software and you have developers around, you could ask for a service which identifies records on insert / update / delete and shows them to you. This could be done e.g. in a REST interface.

**Delta via ID**

If the primary key is an ID and it is set to autoincrement, you could also check your MySQL table for the biggest number and only SELECT those from the source which have a bigger ID than you have already got. This depends of course from the database layout.

Comment: Thx for all the help so far, but i do not have access to their database, and i am not running the licensed version :(

Comment: So what about the idea with the ID? And let the job run very often? There are no other options which are low on resources if you have no access to the database that would match your requirement I think.